# Website creating multiple duplicated pages in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

The issue is with my website. I have noticed that Google is indexing many error pages which is not even available on the website. I think it is PHP script error or htaccess file error. here is the example of the URLs.

http://domain.com/articles/sliding-wardrobe-doors:-a-simple-yet-versatile-design.html/sliding-wardrobe-doors:-a-simple-yet-versatile-design.html

If you see closely, after `.html` extension there is second path continuing the URL. Also, when I open the page in browser, it browse perfectly. It is making my website URL duplicate because Google crawler unable to detect the error.

Comment: Have you tried to validate your website pages with any of the 'html' 'validation services'? I appreciate that they are 'overly critical' but they will find any 'sillies'. You can then fix all the 'obvious faults'. It may be useful. It may be 'tedious' ;-/

Comment: Hey Ryan, Thank you for your feedback. We already tried this and it didn't help us to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a robots.txt file to avoid that crawler detect not existing pages.

See  [How to stop Search Engines from crawling your Website](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/restricting-bots/how-to-stop-search-engines-from-crawling-your-website)

Comment: Hello Franz, We already tried that but i think the problem is with some PHP script error or javascript.

Comment: If this web page is allowed, then you must fix the PHP error. If this web page is not allowed, then you must add it to the robots.txt.

Comment: Actually, Google is making the page itself. iF you see the example page that i have given in the post, it is not proper. The html or php file is making the page itself. As per my knowledge if you add any word in any url which is not on the server then it should land on 404 error page but it is not happening in this case. It is taking proper css and content that i have on actual page.

Comment: You must adapt your .htaccess file to have a pattern for valid urls for your website. sometext.html.sometext.html is invalid.

Comment: Franz, can you guide me how i can make the required changes in htaccess. Any code or something that i can add in htaccess file to resolve this problem.

Comment: `if you add any word in any url which is not on the server then it should land on 404 error page`  this it NOT a default behavior. depends on .htaccess I guess you have all request routed to index.php (or similar) that's why no page results in 404. Well may be a defalut behavior form apache ponint of view, but the most frameworks overwrite it

Comment: You must look to another place for how to use the .htaccess file.

http://serverfault.com/questions/293792/apache-mod-rewrite-to-return-a-404-except-one-directory

http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php?page=all